# Función para imprimir una matriz cuadrada a partir de lista aplanada

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

Tengo esta función que me permite crear una grilla de 3 x 3 a partir de un array aplanado (9 elementos), la cual la genero para un bingo:

```
def distribuir_grilla(arr,len_arr):
    for i in range(0, len(arr), len_arr):
         print ("| {} {} {} |".format(*arr[i:i+len_arr]) )
```

El problema es que a `arr` le agrego el arreglo que me manda de cierta cantidad de números y en `len_arr` le doy el tamaño, pero lo único que me falta es que en el formato de la propia cadena:

```
print ("| {} {} {} |".format(*arr[i:i+len_arr]) )
```

¿Cómo haría para poder reutilizar mi código para crear, por ejemplo, una grilla de 5x5 sin crear otra función? Quisiera reutilizar este código .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tienes varias opciones, una de ellas es usar `str.join`:

```
def distribuir_grilla(arr, len_arr):
    for i in range(0, len(arr), len_arr):
        print("|", " ".join(str(n) for n in arr[i:i + len_arr]), "|")
```

Otra es formatear previamente la propia cadena de formato para adecuar el número de dianas de reemplazo al número de columnas:

```
def distribuir_grilla(arr, len_arr):
    f_str = f"| {'{} ' * len_arr}|"
    for i in range(0, len(arr), len_arr):
         print(f_str.format(*arr[i:i + len_arr]))
```

Si usas Python < 3.6

```
f_str = f"| {'{} ' * len_arr}|"
```

debe sustituirse por

```
 f_str = "| {}|".format('{} ' * len_arr)
```

La segunda opción es más eficiente (eliminada la llamada a `print` para tener solo en cuenta el formato):

> ```
> a = [0] * 10000
>
> %timeit distribuir_grilla1(a, 100)
> 2.52 ms ± 188 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
>
> %timeit distribuir_grilla2(a, 100)
> 1.06 ms ± 14.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
> ```

Salida:

```
>>> distribuir_grilla([1, 2, 3, 7], 2)
| 1 2 |
| 3 7 |

>>> distribuir_grilla([1, 2, 3, 7, 3, 4, 9, 8, 5], 3)
| 1 2 3 |
| 7 3 4 |
| 9 8 5 |

>>> distribuir_grilla([1, 2, 3, 7, 3, 4, 9, 8, 5, 8, 4, 4, 4, 5, 8, 6], 4)
| 1 2 3 7 |
| 3 4 9 8 |
| 5 8 4 4 |
| 4 5 8 6 |

>>> distribuir_grilla([1, 2, 3, 7, 3, 4, 9, 8, 5, 8, 4, 4, 4, 5, 8, 6, 7, 7, 9, 3], 5)
| 1 2 3 7 3 |
| 4 9 8 5 8 |
| 4 4 4 5 8 |
| 6 7 7 9 3 |
```

---

### Edición

La línea `f"{'{} ' * len_arr}"` hace uso de los llamados literales de cadena formateados, introducidos en Python 3.6 ([PEP 498](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/)). Básicamente permite definir un literal de cadena con ciertas dianas de reemplazo que son delimitadas por `{}`. Cada diana de reemplazo es evaluada y se usa el resultado de su evaluación para substituirlo en la cadena final:

```
a = 4
b = 5
print(f"{a} + {b} = {a + b}") #4 + 5 = 9
```

En nuestro caso tenemos un literal de cadena con una única diana de remplazo `{{} ' * len_arr}` que contiene la expresión `'{} ' * len_arr`. Recordemos que podemos multiplicar una cadena por un entero:

```
>>> c = "Hola"
>>> c * 3
'HolaHolaHola'
```

por lo que, si `len_arr` es 3:

```
>>> `{} ' * 3
'{} {} {} '
```

Una vez evaluado se sustituye la diana por esa cadena, quedando `f_str` como:

```
'| {} {} {} |'
```

Comment: hola @FJSevilla significa  esta  f>>>>>  f"| {'{} ' * len_arr}|" detras de la cadena eh estado buscando informacion y no hallo respuesta

Comment: @PaulodelAguila mira la edición de mi respuesta, al final de la misma, a ver si te aclara como funciona.

Comment: me aclaro las dudas, buen aporte

Comment: @FJServilla disculpa por molestarte otra vez pudieras ayudarme con un tema mas?

Comment: Claro, si es directamente sobre la pregunta o la respuesta comenta. Si es algo no directamente relacionado o de suficiente entidad mejor crea otra pregunta.

Comment: es respecto a otra funcion que tengo pudieras responderla cuando la ponga

Comment: como puedo hacerte una consulta directa?

Comment: Paulo no se pueden hacer consultas directas o privada en SO, no es la filosofía del sitio, podríamos usar el chat (que sigue siendo público) pero lo suyo es que crees otra pregunta si consideras que tu problema lo merece y no es una edición de esta pregunta actual. No obstante, estaré ahora un rato por aquí, si crea una nueva pregunta y puedo responderla lo haré si no hay una respuesta mejor de otro usuario.

Comment: si estoy creando una pregunta, entendido @FJSevilla